# Batch file, loop on folder seems to freeze

Tags: batch-file, dos

I need to delete with a batch a list of directories (and subdir) which name starts with a number.

My tree is something like that:

```
|- root
    |--event=aaa
        |--photo
            |--123 
                |--44
                    |--23
                |--89
        |--otherdir
    |--event=bbb
        |--photo
            |--432 
                |--67
                    |--12
                |--32
        |--otherdir
```

I found this working example: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1496

And this is what I wrote

```
@ECHO OFF
SET path=\\mypath
SET dir=\parentDir\

:: loop on event=* folders
FOR /D /R %path%%dir% %%K IN ("*event*") DO (
    :: if an event contains photos ..
    IF EXIST %%K\photo (
        ECHO %%K

        :: loop on dir inside photo folder with a numeric name
        PUSHD %%K\photo ||goto :eof
        FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /ad /b /s ^|findstr /rc:"\\[0-9]"') DO (
            IF EXIST %%~a (
                RD /s /q "%%~a"
            )
        )
        POPD
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO.%%K /photo does not exists
    )
)
ECHO.completed
PAUSE
```

the only problem I found is that the execution seems to freeze when the last /event=xxx folder, and takes quite a long time to ECHO the last line ("completed"). I don't understand why .. any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: How many files in the last dir ? maybe you are just looking at the time it takes a script to run through it.

Comment: the last one is not different from the others, but each folder should contains several subdir / files (more than 600 subdir / files, usually no more than 1-2 files for each subdir)

Comment: .. I noticed that usually the last 30 or 40 folders doesn't contains \photo subdir (so ECHO.%%K /photo does not exists is called)

Comment: and, the parent fodler contains more than 25000 folders and more than 30000 files

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  It will delete every folder under the ****event**** folders that have only numbers in the names.

Currently it will pause on each main folder after merely listing the set of subdirectories that would be deleted, and is not destructive.  If the commands look right then remove the `echo` and the `pause` to activate the RD command to actually delete the folders.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir "*event*" /ad /b ') do (
  for /f "delims=" %%b in (' dir "%%a" /ad /b /s ') do (
       for /f "delims=0123456789" %%c in ("A%%~nxb") do (
        if "%%c"=="A" if exist "%%b\" echo rd /s/q "%%b" 
     )
  )
  pause
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET mypath=.
SET dir=\parentdir\

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( 
 ' dir /ad /s /b "%mypath%%dir%" ^|findstr /r "\\.*event.*\\photo\\[0-9].*" ' ) DO (
 IF EXIST "%%i" ECHO RD /s /q %%i
)
```

This should do as you ask - with some cautions.

I've changed the variable names. `PATH` is not a good name to use because `PATH` is the sequence of directories which the OS searches for an executable.

I've also changed the value to suit my system.

I've added an `ECHO` keyword rather than arbitrarily deleting the target directories - just in case of a typo - gives you a chance at verifying first. This `ECHO` would need to be removed to activate the delete functionality.

The `findstr` regular expression is `\` (which requires an extra `\` as an escape) any number of any characters, `event`, any number of any characters, `\photo\`, a digit then any number of any characters.

Please also note that the `"broken label"` form of comment (`::`) should not be used within a loop. Whereas it (and labels) works within a loop in W7 (and presumably later,) it terminates the loop in some earlier Windows editions, whereas `REM` works for all editions.